# checking if a thread is alive

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, .net-4.0

for a task, potentially taking too long to complete, I'd like a mechanism

1. to start the task
2. return back to user interface (its a web page)
3. periodically/randomly check if the task is complete
4. cancel the executing task when user wishes so
5. get notified when the task completes / fails

what are the possible solutions?

1. **Threads?**
   Start a thread, save its ManagedThreadId, (can you get a thread by its id)
2. write a windows **service**, 
   send the request to service via shared objects/files/db?
   keep interacting with the service the same way (objects/files/db,etc)
   Services?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Sounds like the Task Parallel Library in .NET 4 would be ideal for this...

Comment: @JonSkeet TPL on a ASP.NET Web Page? You sure?

Comment: @Hasan - ah, hadn't seen that bit. Not in the web server itself, but quite possibly in a service *backing* the UI. Tasks could definitely still be relevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes but I think using Tasks for short parallel operations makes more sense. For long running operations threads are probably a better choice.

Comment: @HasanKhan: Why? Tasks provide cancellation, status etc - and you can start them *explicitly saying it's a long-running task*.

Comment: @JonSkeet It will contend for time with other tasks. Can affect scheduling of other tasks perhaps?

Comment: @HasanKhan: Well, if you start it as "long running" the scheduler should take that into account. Fundamentally if you're starting multiple threads, tasks, whatever then they *will* be contending for time.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. Just checked that LongRunningTask actually creates a new thread instead of using thread in a thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host a WCF Service in a Windows Service that will perform the background tasks by adding/reading from a queue which can be maintained either using MSMQ or in a database.

When you add an item for processing; you should get a task id. You should be able to then log the completion/failed/cancel status of the task in db against the task id.

You can have following methods in your WCF contract

```
int ProcessItem(ItemDetails details); // returns task id
bool CancelTask(int taskID); // returns true if successfully cancelled; false otherwise
TaskStatus GetTaskStatus(int taskID); // returns Cancelled, Waiting, Failed or Completed
```

Comment: that looks like a good general solution, that can be paired up with  a Request/Response Message system, sharing a RequestId.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in single process
Have a look at the Task Paralell Library and / or TPL DataFlow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=205053